# Indirect Question [grammar]

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, indirect-question, it-its-itself

I was reviewing this article and had a question about some minor grammar issues.

The whole sentence is

> "The current work attempts to solve this gap in CE knowledge by investigating how security affects the purchase decision, what personal factors are relevant in this scenario, and what effects does framing have on the purchase decision."

I was wondering what is wrong with the "and what effects does framing have on the purchase decision" sentence. I think the verb is wrong, but just don't know what other grammar issues it has. If it is wrong, may I have an explanation as well?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be “and what effects framing has . . .” to keep it parallel.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much :)